# magento 2.4.6 installation failed due to Plugin initialization failed (require(app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php): Failed to open stream

Tags: composer, magento2.4.6, php8.1

PHP version:  8.1

composer: 2.2.0

Trying to fresh installed Magento open source 2.4.6 using the below command

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.6 magento246
```

and getting the below error:

```
 - Installing composer/pcre (3.1.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing composer/class-map-generator (1.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing composer/metadata-minifier (1.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing composer/spdx-licenses (1.5.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing squizlabs/php_codesniffer (3.7.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer (v0.7.2): Extracting archive
Plugin initialization failed (require(app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory), uninstalling plugin
  - Removing dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer (v0.7.2)
    Install of dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer failed

                                                                                                           
  [ErrorException]                                                                                         
  require(app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory  
                                                                                                           

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

**Error message:**

```
    Plugin initialization failed (require(app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory), uninstalling plugin
  - Removing dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer (v0.7.2)
    Install of dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer failed

                                                                                                           
  [ErrorException]                                                                                         
  require(app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: May i suggest you to check the permissions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The issue has been resolved after upgrading the composer version to the latest.**

```
sudo composer selfupdate --2
composer -v


   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
Composer version 2.5.8 2023-06-09 17:13:21
```

I think the issue is with the [More secure plugin execution concept](https://blog.packagist.com/composer-2-2/#more-secure-plugin-execution) of the composer.

**allow-plugins** is used on  mqagento composer.json for secure magento  code and  composer 2.2.0 version might has some issue that why the issue happen.

see

```
"allow-plugins": {
    "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
    "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true,
    "magento/*": true,
    "php-http/discovery": true
},
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you can create an empty app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php file in your Magento installation.

Comment: thanks but i donot think it right idea as this file Magento will create automatically